# Add one day to `Time.now.to_i`

Tags: ruby

I am generating a time by `Time.now.to_i`. What is the simplest way to also add one day to it?

Comment: I am perplexed by your choice of "best" answer. There have been two answers so far. One answered your question, the other answered a question you did not ask, yet you selected the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Date` class provides a `+` operator that could serve as an alternative to using `Time`.

```
require 'date'

now = Date.today
puts now.to_s
=> "2015-07-24"
puts (now+1).to_s
=> "2015-07-25"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Time.now.to_i + 60 * 60 * 24
```

..................